# The convergence interval for trigonometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the method one can use to determine the interval of convergence for the series $\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\cos(n\pi)\cot^n(x)}{n(n+1)}$. For me it seems that I cannot transform it into power series and the integral method doesn't work also, as well as ratio test doesn't seem to fit.

$$\Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\cos(n\pi)\cot^n(x)}{n(n+1)} = \left[ \cot(x) = y \right] = \Sigma^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-y)^n}{n(n+1)}$$

Then using ratio test: $$\frac{(-y)^{n+1} n(n+1)}{(-y)^{n}(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{-n y}{n+2} \\ lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{-n y}{n+2} = -y$$
For series to converge:  $-y < 1 \Rightarrow y > -1 \Rightarrow \cot(x) > 1 \iff x \in[\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n; \frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n[ \text{ where } n \in Z^+$
Is it correct?

Comment: Have you tried the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)?

Comment: What happens if we substitute $\cot(x)=y$? (Also Remember that $\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^n$)

Comment: @SewerKeeper Ok, now I tried to compute the interval of convergence and wanted to make sure, if it's correct.

Comment: @user67 Take absolute values, in the ratio test. It would look better to come to $-1\leq y \leq 1$ I would say (note that $\pm 1$ you need to examine separately)

Comment: Wait, the ratio test works with positive term series, Is this the case? Moreover, do you know how to find the interval of convergence of a Power series?

Comment: @SewerKeeper No, that's not the case. I thought that you can find the convergence interval for power series using ratio test as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \cot{x}$, the series becomes

$$
\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{y^n}{n(n+1)}
$$

If we take the absolute value:

$$
\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{|y|^n}{n(n+1)}
$$

For the necessary condition of convergence, the general term must verify
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{|y|^n}{n(n+1)} = 0
$$

therefore $|y|\le 1$ (why?)

So

$$
\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{|y|^n}{n(n+1)} \le \sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} =\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+n}\le\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
$$
which converges.

Hence $|y|\le 1$, so $-1<\cot x < 1$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: So, then the convergence interval is $[\frac{-\pi}{4}+\pi n; \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi n]$?

Comment: Since the function $x \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(\cot x)^n}{n(n+1)}$ is $\pi$-periodic, you can consider the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.